# Issues with "There is already an object named 'xxx' in the database'

Tags: sql

I'm fairly new to SQL so this may be an easy mistake, but I haven't been able to find a solid solution anywhere else. Problem is whenever I try to use my temp table, it tells me it cannot be used because there is already an object with that name. I frequently try switching up the names, and sometimes it'll let me work with the table for a little while, but it never lasts for long. Am I dropping the table incorrectly? Also, I've had people suggest to just use a permanent table, but this database does not allow me to do that.

```
create table #RandomTableName(NameOfObject varchar(50), NameOfCounter varchar(50), SampledValue decimal)

select vPerformanceRule.ObjectName, vPerformanceRule.CounterName, Perf.vPerfRaw.SampleValue

into #RandomTableName

from vPerformanceRule, vPerformanceRuleInstance, Perf.vPerfRaw
where (ObjectName like 'Processor' AND CounterName like '% Processor Time')
OR(ObjectName like 'System' AND CounterName like 'Processor Queue Length')
OR(ObjectName like 'Memory' AND CounterName like 'Pages/Sec')
OR(ObjectName like 'Physical Disk' AND CounterName like 'Avg. Disk Queue Length')
OR(ObjectName like 'Physical Disk' AND CounterName like 'Avg. Disk sec/Read')
OR(ObjectName like 'Physical Disk' and CounterName like '% Disk Time')
OR(ObjectName like 'Logical Disk' and CounterName like '% Free Space' AND SampleValue > 70 AND SampleValue < 100)
order by ObjectName, SampleValue

drop table #RandomTableName
```

Comment: Side note: The order by in your select is totally useless - tables do NOT have an intrinsic sort order unless you create one. By ordering you push additional processing into the select part that is useless later sa #RandomTableName is NOT SORTED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the table first, which is fine, but then you are doing a Select Into, which is trying to create another temp table with the same name.  If you are using the create table syntax, then your select should look like this `insert into #RandomTableName (nameOfObject, NameOfCounter, SampledValue)
select vPerformanceRule.ObjectName, vPerformanceRule.CounterName, Perf.vPerfRaw.SampleValue
from......`

Us the select into when you don't want to create your table ahead of time.

Comment: To be more exact - SELECT INTO creates the table with the exact same field data type definitions as the original table. There is no need to create the table first - nothing is gained in your case.